# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am trying to copy data from CSV to mysql using **shell script** where I am all new. And I am working with my test server.

```
mysql -u root -proot csv_imports -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/html/$_csv_directory/$_csv_files' REPLACE INTO TABLE temp_test_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

I am getting error

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

If I am not working on localhost, why its giving me error of **'root'@'localhost'**?

then I tried

```
mysql -h name-database-db-instance.something.some-server.com -P 3306 -u root -proot -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/test.server.re/public_html/csv_files/$_csv_files' REPLACE INTO TABLE table_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

now its giving me error:

> Access denied for user 'codered_db_user'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: on which server is the database ?

Comment: I don't see your mysql command mentioning a server name: if not, then that would explain that it tries to connect to a server on localhost.

Comment: the password you give `-proot`  must be set on database, and user root must be allowed in mysql. (`grant connect to root`)

Comment: @dhag now I have set server name. but still issue is there. Please check I have edited question!

Comment: To start with get rid of all the CSV stuff and just try to connect.  Does it work if you do `mysql -h servername -u root -proot`?

Comment: @DavidKing when I tried with **servername** still its giving me error :

`Access denied for user 'codered_db_user'@'%' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about "localhost" you need to understand a little bit about MySQL users.

A user in MySQL is actually made up of two things:

- the username
- a network location

So the user `'root'@'localhost'` makes up a user login for root to login from localhost. With me so far?

You are actually seeing it come up because if you do not specify a host your MySQL client will default to connect to a MySQL instance running on localhost.

So from MySQL servers point of view the login attempt is initiated by root coming from the localhost hence `'root'@'localhost'`.

Regarding your password I seem to recall that some versions of the client need you to use `--password` not `-p` if you are specifying the password on the command line.

Comment: yes I got you. I updated my question. Next I have specified server still there is error!! Please check updation! Thanks for efforts, its helping me!